# How to make a galilean cannon with balls falling/rebounding straight

Tags: experimental-physics, building-physics

[image]

Here is what I mean by galilean cannon, simply letting balls fall, but hard to experiment though... First, I tried to drop 2 balls with my hands, but balls do not rebound straight and I get enormous uncertainty... I tried then to drill them which works but my rebounding balls lose a lot of "rebounding power" which falsify my results

Comment: There are two things deforming to make a rebound- the floor and the ball.  If the rebound is not straight, that just indicates an asymmetry somewhere (which to some degree can't be avoided) so what can you do to make it more symmetric?

Comment: The asymmetry comes from the axis of the balls. The balls have to be on the same axis, otherwise they won't rebound straight.  That's why drill them and then aline them with a thread works perfectly, but it decreases the "rebouding power" of the balls

Comment: A perfectly flat floor is needed - do you have one? And when you let go do your hands inadvertently impart a spin to the ball? Ever played snooker?

Comment: What about all the balls the same size but hollow to give different masses? then a tube...

Comment: Yes, but then balls do have the same composition and "rebounding power". I tried a Tube too, Wich sometimes works well, but the problem still the same. The balls have to fall and rebound straight to neglect friction

Comment: Yes my floor is perfect ( I do it inside). It's not really spin, but with my hands the balls are not necessary on the same axis and then the upper ball rebound vertically

Comment: Floors may seem perfect but placement of studs and rebar and all else do impose some asymmetry.  If you are using a string to guide, see what happens when the guide is only available on the way down or partway down.  You can also spin balls to see how balanced they are.

Comment: I don't think your floor is "perfect" is it measured to less than 0.01mm per meter for surface flatness? any deviation will cause the ball to not rebound perfectly.

Comment: You don't need that many layers to do this demonstration.  Using just a ping pong ball on top of a basketball will probably make a pretty cool looking demo